# SQL database connection name different to database name

Tags: sql-server, database, webmatrix

I am using Webmatrix and created an app that works perfectly when I connect to a database and the database connection name are the same. When you add a database connection in Webmatrix, it automatically creates the database connection name the same as the SQL database name.

I am creating a dev/test environment and want to just reference a different database name but keep the connection name the same so I don't have to change all database open names in my app.

I have gone into web.Config and change the name of my connection but it doesn't work. I can see the database connection and even the data in the tables in the database window, but login into the application I created doesn't work (Which does for the production environment).

Production connection string:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="VouchFor"
    connectionString="server=servername;Pwd=xxxxxx;uid=user;Database=VouchFor"  
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Is there a limitation with Webmatrix and having a different connection name and database name? 
See connection name is different to database name below:

Test/Dev connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="VouchFor"
    connectionString="server=servername;Pwd=xxxxxx;uid=user;Database=VouchForTest"  
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Please be more specific - telling us "it doesn't work" doesn't help. What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Greg - When I log in it says that is the incorrect user/password

Answer (score 1):

If you copied the database from one server to another, you first need to ensure that the user account has been created on the new server, and that the user accounts are not "orphaned". See https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/274188 for full details, but in essence, you need to run the following on the target server:

```
Use VouchForTest
go
sp_change_users_login 'update_one', 'user', 'user'
```

where 'user' is the name of the login.